# The meaning of credit

Tags: meaning

Here's part of a conversation:

> Mrs. Parker: Can't we get a loan from the bank?
>   Mr. Parker: Actually, I asked them the other day.
>   Mrs. Parker: What did they answer?
>   Mr. Parker: They said I didn't have enough credit with the bank.

I looked *credit* up in [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/credit) and found the following:

> a record of how well you have paid your bills in the past

Is this the right meaning in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > a record of how well you have paid your bills in the past
>
> Is this the right meaning [of *credit*] in this context?

Not exactly. Your *credit*, properly, expresses the degree of faith which somebody has in you—in the bank's case, the degree of its faith that you will repay a loan. Your "credit history"—your past record of paying your obligations—is no doubt an important contributor to that faith, but there are other factors the bank also considers, such as your income and your employment prospects, and what assets you can put up for security.

Comment: Then the following definition seems better: _the status of being trusted to pay back money to somebody who lends it to you_. Source: [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/credit_1?q=credit)

Comment: @Mori Yes, that's what banks mean when they speak of extending credit to borrowers.

Comment: credit has many meanings in other contexts, including well defined meanings in accounting.  Just fyi, since it can be easy to get them confused.

Comment: I don't like your answer because you rebutted the suggested meaning by the OP, substituted it for another one, but the most important thing is that you didn't even try to explain why the meaning suggested by the OP is not right.